# Source(s) for hourly euro/usd exchange rate historic data?

Tags: currency, foreign-exchange, historical-data

I'm looking for historic data for the euro/usd exchange rate with an hourly interval. The data should look back several months.

Unfortunately I have been unable to find a source providing this data, even paid services. If anyone could suggest a source that does provide hourly information, that'd be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the FX section of the [quantitative finance SE data wiki](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/141/1106).

---

### Foreign Exchange

- [OANDA Historical Exchange Rates](http://www.oanda.com/currency/historical-rates/)
- [Converterhub Current/Historical Currency Rates](http://www.converterhub.com/currencytrends)
- [Dukascopy - Historical FX prices; XML and CSV](http://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/data_feed/historical/)
- [ForexForums Historical Data - Historical FX downloads via Amazon S3](http://forexforums.dailyfx.com/free-strategy-trader-historical-data/220967-free-strategy-trader-historical-data.html)
- [GAIN Capital - Historical FX rates (in ZIP format)](http://ratedata.gaincapital.com/)

Comment: Are you sure they provide hourly ratios? I looked at them and could only find daily values.

Comment: @Tom I remember that one of them provides hourly data, don't remember which.  You may have to do some digging, but I am confident this data can be found.

Comment: dukascopy historically provides 10s data (and for recent years tick data), that can easily be aggregated into hourly data.

Comment: A lot of link rot has crept in over 6½ years, unfortunately. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: Better link for OANDA: https://developer.oanda.com/rest-live/rates/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify whether you wanted raw data, or just a website to look it up on. I use [XE's currency charts](https://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=GBP&to=AUD) to find what I need; it provides exchange rates to the hour, back for at least a few weeks, and to the quarter-hour in the past few days, for free.

I do wish I had a source of raw data, so I could write a script and just type the date and time I need. I had a quick look at the HTTP responses that page uses and didn't find anything easy, only a long string of alphanumeric characters. I assume the code that interprets it is too obfuscated for it to be worth my time deciphering it, and that doing so would violate their terms of service. So I just mutter as I zoom and scroll around the graph, hover the mouse pointer, and memorise the numerals.